# how to filter string of dictionary from a list of python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list tht contains strings, and those string could be a simple string or key value pair in a string. Please see below sample

```
c = ['Success, no result', 'num_parts: 55', 'num_boards: 2', 'xyz', 'adsqwrqw']
```

I know a way to Convert String to List of dictionaries  using `json.loads() + replace()` method. But the condition is to have all elements as dictionary.

But in my case, a list contains a string, and dictionary as a string. How to filter in such condition?

Any suggestion

Comment: You problem is not clear. Can you please add more and exact details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for th `":"` in the string as that is the key which differentiates  dictionary compliant strings like this :-

```py
lst = ['Success, no result', 'num_parts: 55', 'num_boards: 2', 'xyz', 'adsqwrqw']
DictL, StrL = [], []

for i in lst:
    if ":" in i:
        DictL.append(i)
    else:
        StrL.append(i)
```

You can also further compress it to a List comprehension like this :-

```py
lst = ['Success, no result', 'num_parts: 55', 'num_boards: 2', 'xyz', 'adsqwrqw']

DictL, StrL = [i for i in lst if ":" in i], [i for i in lst if ":" not in i]
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can check if ': ' is in the string by a simple if command:

```
for string in c:
   if ': ' in string:
      #do something with dictionary string
   else:
      #do something with simple string
```